# HTML adding CRUD button which will get specific thing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, get, crud

I have a problem with my current project. I am working on my personal project where I am using CRUD in HTML and Node.js. I faced the problem while creating Get (with given ID) button. While button Get - which gives me all data from DB - is working, the one with specific ID is not. Here I am attaching screen shots of my source code:

```js
//Get - function from SQL Server
app.get('/people', (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM peopledb.people' , (err, rows, fields) =>{
    if(!err)
    res.send(rows);
    else
    console.log(err);
  })
})



//Get - function from SQL with given ID

app.get('/people/:id', (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM peopledb.people WHERE PplID = ?' ,[req.params.id] ,(err, rows, fields) =>{
    if(!err)
    res.send(rows);
    else
    console.log(err);
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
        <form action="/people" method="GET" class="getbutton">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Get People from Database" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="/people/" method="GET">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="GetUnique" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Get person by ID"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I hope I explained you everything clear and understandable.
Summing up, I just want the second button to forward me to page /people/(given ID in input box). After clicking the button my URL request is: localhost:X/people/?, while it should be: localhost:X/poeple/(given ID).

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what could exactly be wrong. First of all You should use browser's dev tools (network) and check the response of your request.